# UITableViewCell hide content when is not visible

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have gif animated pictures in some uitableview rows,

When there is a lot of gifs in tableview CPU usage is going to be very high,

So I want to hide these gifs when their row is not visible,

How can I do that ?

How can I achieve not visible cells row's indexPath ?

After that I can hide the gif like that :

```
UITableViewCell *celll = [ tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
UIImageView *gif = (UIImageView*)[celll viewWithTag:30000];
gif.hidden = TRUE;
```

So I must get not visible cells indexPath's in a loop.

Comment: If you are using reusable cells, than you don't have to do that, UITableView handles all of that for you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you don't need to do that as long as you properly use reusable cells.
Nevertheless, if you do want to do that, you can use `tableView:didEndDisplayingCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` method on `UITableViewDelegate`:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndDisplayingCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell
                                              forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UIImageView *gif = (UIImageView*)[celll viewWithTag:30000];
    gif.hidden = YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you'll put the line:

```
    NSLog(@"%@",indexPath);
```

as the first line of the method:

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

You'll realise that it's done automatically. Only the visible cells, i.e the one that appears on the screen, are the one you present the data for.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for poor english.You had not posted code about how your cellForRowAtIndexPath implementation look like,i will suggest to make your cellForRowAtIndexPath like below.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"YOURIDENTIFIERSTRING";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeReusableCellWithIdentifier: CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath]; 

   // Configure the cell here …

   return cell;
}
```

This way only those many cells will be created which are visible on device and once row goes out of device view it will be reuse for new row. Please check [apple doc for tableview](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:).